# hdfs random access got poor performance compared with random reading local disk

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, random-access

I made a test to test the random read performance of hdfs, modified the codes to avoid reading meta file for each block, and didn't use transferTo of FileChannel, but it got very poor performance compared with random access local disk, I used hadoop1.1.2, does anybody know why?

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: Yeah... without code I can only say that HDFS is just not designed to be fast for random access

Comment: thanks very much, I have got the solution, there are two reason which lead to hdfs' poor random access.

Comment: thanks very much, I have got the solution, there are two reason which lead to hdfs' poor random access performance. 1. DataNode costs lots of time to read meta file, which is not used now; 2. DataNode create a new DataXceiver(thread) each time receiving a request to access block, which will increase the cost of GC. Do you agree with them?